How do I pull in the highest rating of a particular item on PowerBI?
For full background, I have loaded an excel dataset onto PowerBI for reporting purposes so if further manipulation of data needs to happen, I'm open to solutions that require me to manipulate the data on excel.
Obviously my dataset is more complicated but for illustrative purposes, I have a table with columns: Company, Item, Rating. Each company gives each item a rating from 1-4. However, the companies may rate the item more than once - see attached image.

So the questions is, on PowerBI, how would I pull the data through into a chart or table such that only the max ratings of each item is shown?
I would also like to have a chart or table showing the number of items a company has with a particular rating.
As I said, I don't mind doing further excel manipulation, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is. Is the best way to create a unique list of items with their max ratings and then use a v/xlookup to assign new ratings to the original list? If so, what would the easiest way be to create the unique list with max ratings?
I've tried creating a chart and table the normal way on PowerBI, but it just seems to add up all the ratings related to each item. I then thought to divide the total rating number by the number of instances of each item but realised quickly that that's just calculating the average rating for an item which won't get me what I want. At this point I know what I want the result to look like but I just have no clue how to get there and I have no idea how to search for it.

I would personally handle this at Power Query stage (No complex formulas... Just few clicks)

Select the Company and Item columns.

Go to the Transform tab, click on Group By.

In the Group By window, select Company and Item.

Add a new aggregation by clicking on Add Aggregation, set the new column name (e.g., Max Rating), and use the Max function on the Rating column.


Sample Data

Group By

and then

Final Output

